# Go to parent activity inside button's onClick() method in a fragment

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, android-button

Basically, each of my all fragments has its own activity. however, when switch to a screen. I just switch activities and each activity immediately call its own fragment. So inside a fragment I have a button and I am overriding onClick() method of the button. after i published the app i got a crash report that says onClick() getting nullException. I am not sure what it causes because I have been testing it and havent reproduced the issue. probably when I call the parent class , I am getting nullException. I am trying to goto Parent activity once this button get invoked. here is the code.

```
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent doneActivity = null;
            try {
                if(Class.forName(parentActivity) != null){
                doneActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), Class.forName(parentActivity));
                doneActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                }else{
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  } 
            startActivity(doneActivity);            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   }else{
       finish();
   }
```

Basically, just remove the "getActivity()." part. I haven't tested it, but it might work

Comment: I added if statement after I found the crash.. so its not gonna make any difference. I think I need to use getActivity().getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity() in Fragment